# RegEx: capture all the phrases with hyphen in them

Tags: regex, editpad

I have a very long list of words that after converting from another format, some of the words in it are hyphenated. for example:

```
book, im-moral, law
intesti-nal, lung
flimflam*, fly-by-night*, illegal,
```

How can I capture all the phrases that have hyphen in them? In case of above example it would be:

```
im-moral
intesti-nal
fly-by-night
```

**RegEx flavor: regular expressions engine implemented in EditPad Pro 7**

Comment: Should probably be `(-[a-zA-Z]+)+`, otherwise there will be a lot of false positives, as * also matches 0 occurences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wuHmOkG1cLMscHUnutd6?p=preview) link. As anubhava mentioned, we can use the same regexp. I have also added a simple example to check it.

`

```
var str = 'book, im-moral,law,intesti-nal,lung, flimflam*, fly-by-night*, illegal';

var re = /([a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)+)/gi;
var found = str.match(re);
alert(found)
```

`